# Intuition for bandwidth and degrees of freedom in kernel smoothers

Tags: intuition, kernel-smoothing, degrees-of-freedom, smoothing

For Kernel smoothers such as local polynomial regression smoothers (the Nadaraya-Watson smoother), we consider $y = m(x) + \epsilon$, for $m(x)$ some smooth function we are trying to estimate and $\epsilon$ a random error term with zero mean and constant variance. we perform a local weighted regression at $x$, with data $(x_j,y_j)$ weighted by $l_j$ given by

\begin{equation}
     l_j = \frac{w_j}{\sum_{k=1}^n w_k} \text{ for } w_j = K\left(\frac{x - x_j}{h}\right)
\end{equation}

We can define a smoothing matrix $S$ such that our prediction $\hat{Y} = \hat{m}(x) = SY$.
I would like to gain a better intuition for the bandwidth $h$, and in particular how it relates to the trace of the smoothing matrix $S$, which can be seen as a notion for degrees of freedom.
I believe that as $h$ increases, the level of smoothing will increase, meaning local predictions will be more similar and the bias of the predictor will increase, but the variance will decrease.
In particular as $h \to \infty$, the weights are uniform for all points. Then for the Nadaraya-Watson smoother we simply predict a constant function and for a local polynomial regression we predict a global polynomial. And as $h \to 0$ the weight for the prediction at point $x_j$ will tend to 0 for all $k\neq j$ and to 1 for $j$ and so the predictions will simply be the data. Loosely speaking, this shows for $h \to \infty$ we have a fixed number of "parameters"(e.g. 1 in Nadaraya-Watson case) equal to the order of the local linear regression plus one. And as $h \to 0$ we have $n$ "parameters", the prediction for each point. 
I believe that as h increases, $\nu = tr(S)$ will be monotonically decreasing, indicating fewer "parameters" and a simpler model.
Questions:

- Is this notion of degrees of freedom sensible (in an intuitive, non-rigorous way)?
- What is a good intuition for the meaning of $h$?
- What is a good intuition for the meaning of $\nu = tr(S)$?
- Is $\nu = tr(S)$ monotonically decreasing with $h$?